# Inserting cli options into virtualenv.cli_run within a python file

Tags: python, virtualenv

[Problem Code Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8F3sO.png)

I want to write a Python script that creates a new virtual environment with the following [*virtualenv*](https://pypi.org/project/virtualenv/) CLI options:

> `--app-data APP_DATA` (a folder APP_DATA for the cache)
>
> `--seeder {app-data,pip}`

If I give those two as strings in a list (see picture) I get:

```
TypeError: options must be of type VirtualEnvOptions
```

Comment: No screenshots of text (or code)! Instead copy-paste the text into the question.

Comment: If you put your code as text in your question, a person who has the same question can reach here via a search engine easily.

Comment: ok going to change it soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [*virtualenv*'s documentation section "Programmatic API"](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide.html#programmatic-api), this seems like the following should work:

```py
from virtualenv import cli_run

cli_run(['path/to/venv', '--app-data', 'path/to/app_data', '--seeder', 'app-data'])
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `cli_run` as part of virtualenv, you don't need to include the first argument, in this case "venv".

this should work:

```
from virtualenv import cli_run
cli_run(["--app-data APP_DATA", "--seeder {app-data,pip}"]);
```

Comment: My Problem is not about the programm name. I am just naming my folder for my virtualenvironment venv . The first argument passend to the method should refer to directory.
I want to pass the options I mentioned above (--app-data APP_DATA, --seeder {app-data,pip}) to the script. How do I pass those the cli_run method?